# GAE Race condition .get() and .put()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am saving one of the fields in datastore using:

```
self.user.expiration_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
self.user.put()
```

I am using Webapp2. After saving the user expiration date, I redirect the user to a method, where the following code is written.

```
user = User.all().filter('email =', self.session.get('email'))

digest = self.session.get('passwd').encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
user = user.filter('passwd =', digest).get()
self.user = user
```

However, after this, when I check for the expiration_date, its Null or previous value.

What should I do here to get correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of Eventual Consistency in a NoSQL Datastore. This section explains what is up. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#h.w3kz4fze562t

Basically there is a slight delay between when an entity is written and when those writes will be seen by a query. If you refetch the entity by its key, you will avoid this problem.

If you can replace the `User.all()` query with a `User.get_by_id()` call and then compare `user.email == session.get('email') and user.password == digest` then you can avoid it.

Comment: If I have id, then I dont need to use the email comparision, right? ID shall be unique in the model.

Comment: That's right, if you have the id then you can construct a key and just use get. Or you can use get_by_id (I forget the db syntax) that does the same thing under the covers. The point is, if you get the user by key/id and not by query, then you will get a consistent entity.